# Multiple Billing Address for Multiple items in cart, Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, shipping-address, billing-address

Magento give functionality to use multiple Shipping address.
I want to add multiple products in cart with below condition:

```
1. Cart has multiple items 
2. Shipping Address can be different for all.
3. Billing Address can be different for all.
```

How can I achieve the 3rd?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the below links might help you fully but you might want to have a look.

The multi-shipment feature allows purchased items to be shipped to multiple address. For example, when a customer buys two items A and B, it is possible to have the items shipped to two different addresses. The addresses to be used can be created during checkout, or selected from existing addresses.

http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/Episerver-Commerce/8/Shipping/Multi-shipment-examples/

http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-multishipping-checkout/

Comment: Thanks, Multiple Shipping allowed in magento bydefault, I need a way to add multiple billing at the same time.